# Test ascending Javascript array of Date objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, date

I have a javascript array of Date objects, which I'd like to **test** for ascendingness. This is what I built, but I am kind of disappointed by it. Any suggestion?

```
function isAscending(timeLine) {
  if (timeLine.length < 2)
    return true;

  for(var i=1; i < timeLine.length; i++) {
    if(timeLine[i-1] > timeLine[i])
      return false;
  }
  return true;   
}
```

(I was hoping for something more expressive, built-in, some library math function etc.)

Comment: I blame LINQ for making people think that if the code is readable and understandable, there is something wrong with it ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the simplest way to do it; don't be disappointed.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
function isAscending(timeLine){
    var i=0, L= timeLine.length-1;
    while(i<L){
        if(timeLine[i]> timeLine[++i]) return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: It only reads the length of the array once, rather than on each pass through the loop. And it saves a separate test for an array with one member.

Comment: this is indeed the "optimized" version of what I did myself. Less readable and still O(N) complexity (so no impressive benefit). But thanks for the effort anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

es6 way

```
let isAscending = timeLine => 
    timeLine.every( (v, i, a) => a.length - 1 === i || v < a[i + 1] )
```